# Data contains same values for the given ID. After grouping it i want the resultant in pandas dataframe with only one entry per ID

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get unique value from the columns after grouping the dataframe with a key.

For example

```
Id    Col1     Col2   Col3
1     2         5      8
1     2         5      8
1     2         5      8
2     5         6      9
2     5         6      9
2     5         6      9
3     5         6      9
3     5         6      9
3     5         6      9
4     2         5      8
4     2         5      8 
4     2         5      8
```

so i want to group by ID and get only unique values from the columns in a data frame.
output:

```
Id    Col1     Col2   Col3
1     2         5      8
2     5         6      9
3     5         6      9
4     2         5      8
```

Comment: I think `df = df.drop_duplicates()` should working, if not, please change data sample for explain why.

Comment: No you are not getting my question. I want the resultant in a datframe containing the ID and the unique value it holds

Comment: sure, so change data sample, because now my solution working perfectly.

Comment: Done please check now. If i do drop_duplicates the values in the Id 3 and 4 will also go right?

Comment: sure, still working nice.